# SSH Freezes/Lags after successful login and showing prompt

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a Raspberry Pi from a local network (all devices on the same Wi-Fi). When doing this from my Windows machine, everything works normally. But when I use my Ubuntu machine, it logs in, shows me the prompt `pi@raspberrypi:~$` and then either completely freezes, where I can't input anything and I can't log out, or it has a lag of over 30 sec for keyboard inputs to show up in the terminal. I've tried setting `UseDNS no` and logging in without X11 forwarding and with compression, but those don't help.

Comment: Try enabling verbose mode (`ssh -v pi`) and see if that gives any clues.

Comment: The initial part where it connects, authenticates and logs in all works perfectly fine. I don't see anything in the verbose output to suggest something is wrong

Comment: I wonder if there is something odd or different about the TTY settings (probably on the RPi end).  Try `ssh -t pi stty -a` from both Windows and Linux and compare the results.  The lag part is very odd though.

Comment: @GregA.Woods I tried that... Can't say I understood the output, but the only thing that's different between the two is the speed. Windows says 9600 baud, Ubuntu says 38400 baud

Comment: Update: Set the speed on Ubuntu using `stty 9600` and tried again... did not help

Comment: Yeah, speed is ignored for pseudo-TTYs.  You say you tried "with compression", but have you tried making sure compression is disabled?  Also, when it works but with extreme lag, does the verbose output (try with two or three '-v' options) say anything different when typing (and/or receiving output)?

Comment: I haven't tried making sure. I just ran it with the -C flag. How would I make sure? Also the verbose output stops after the login is complete, so I can't say if anything is different

Comment: Does a network packet tracer such as wireshark show anything different between a connection from Windows versus one from Ubuntu?

Comment: On Ubuntu I see a steady stream of packets and dropped packets. The Raspberry Pi uses SSHv2 protocol and Ubuntu uses TCP. On Windows, after the initial query from the raspberry pi to 24.0.0.251 using MDNS, I can't see any packets when I filter by the ip4 address of the Pi